# cant install google-chrome on amazon red hat server

Tags: google-chrome, fedora, redhat-enterprise-linux, amazon-ec2, dependencies

I am trying to install google-chrome on Amazon server

```
NAME="Amazon Linux AMI"
VERSION="2018.03"
ID="amzn"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="2018.03"
PRETTY_NAME="Amazon Linux AMI 2018.03"
ANSI_COLOR="0;33"
```

by following https://access.redhat.com/discussions/917293

but it gives me dependency errors as below and does not install

> ```
> --> Processing Dependency: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit) for package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64
> --> Finished Dependency Resolution
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libappindicator3.so.1()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libatspi.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: xdg-utils
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: liberation-fonts
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libgdk-3.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libXss.so.1()(64bit)
> Error: Package: google-chrome-stable-71.0.3578.98-1.x86_64 (/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64)
>            Requires: libgtk-3.so.0()(64bit)
>  You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
> ```

Even tried doing the work around as mentioned with --skip-broken , yet it did not get installed ,

```
yum list installed google-chrome
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Error: No matching Packages to list
```

tried resolving the dependencies but strangely the **packages are not there on the amazon yum repos**

```
 yum search libappindicator3
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Warning: No matches found for: libappindicator3
No matches found
```

then followed this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836219/centos-6-5-howto-install-gtk-version-2-8-0

```
yum install gtk+-devel gtk2-devel
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * amzn-main: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
 * amzn-updates: packages.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                                                              | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                                                           | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
No package gtk+-devel available.
No package gtk2-devel available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

then i found out the rpm repo and tried to install directly from that with again recursive dependencies

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

```
rpm -ivh http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
Retrieving http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
warning: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.qvgrSF: Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID f4a80eb5: NOKEY
error: Failed dependencies:
    atk-devel >= 1.29.4-2 is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    cairo-devel >= 1.6.0-1 is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    gdk-pixbuf2-devel is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    glib2-devel >= 2.28.0-1 is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    gtk2 = 2.24.31-1.el7 is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libXcomposite-devel is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libXcursor-devel is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libatk-1.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libgailutil.so.18()(64bit) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0()(64bit) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pango-devel >= 1.20.0-1 is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(atk) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(cairo) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(gdk-pixbuf-2.0) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(gio-2.0) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(pango) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(pangocairo) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
    pkgconfig(pangoft2) is needed by gtk2-devel-2.24.31-1.el7.x86_64
```

i literally tried resolving all the missing packages but they are not there and i cant get chrome to install . 
.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it , got it to install the latest chrome version and got it to work in headless mode ,

used a very effective script on https://intoli.com/blog/installing-google-chrome-on-centos/

quickest way is to run command : `curl https://intoli.com/install-google-chrome.sh | bash` .

which installed all the dependencies and installed the app with latest stable version .

The final goal was to be able to run it with selenium , 
with some minor tweaks to allow it to run on headless mode , got it working with selenium .

```
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
browser = webdriver.Chrome('/path_to_chrome_driver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is that the first linked tutorial (access.redhat.com/...) is NOT for a AMI.

Amazon AMI has the ability and appears to have taken such ability to limit the repos and availability of packages in it's AMI might consider working with the following AMI:

https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B00KWBZVK6/ref=ptnr_catgtm_centos

This one allows for upstream repo updates and additions unlike the one you mentioned using.